# Post or during apocalypse book

Tags: story-identification

I was scrolling through Facebook a few years back and I came across a book about the Earth's surface being too hot to live on. Humanity  was forced to go underground. It was advertised, I don’t have much to go on. It sounded like a good book.

It’s not Metro.

Answer (score 2):

Was it a book or a online short novel? If the latter, it *might* have been a fanfic based on [the *Lacuna* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/82497-lacuna), where it turns out that the Toralii's destruction of Earth had fallen short of its target - while the surface was burned and rendered uninhabitable, a self-sustaining fraction of humanity had secretly escaped inside the Earth using indestructium tubes converted to giant drills. After several years, they were able to reach the core, where they installed a giant vacuum chamber in what they dubbed the Lagrange Zero point - where shielding from the Earth's gravity allowed space jump engines to work, giving them a covert access to the outside.

(Another series with the surface of the Earth **metaphorically** "too hot" to survive, and people underground, is Asimov's "prequel" to the Foundation Cycle, starting with *Pebble in the Sky* and *Caves of Steel*, but I think you'd remember if it was *that*).

Answer (score 2):

[Global Burning?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33832238-global-burning?ac=1&from_search=true) by  Jonathan Sturak

> It's the year 2045 and global warming has turned the world into a fireball. Nothing can survive outside and the last humans are confined to the underground.

Comment: It is neither of those titles, very close to the plot. This book was released  maybe 2-6 years ago. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

How about [SevenEves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves) by Neal Stephenson? Published in 2015, it's about how humanity adapts after the moon explodes and the resulting debris showers (the Hard Rain) boil the oceans and cause the surface to become uninhabitable. The bulk of the book is about survivors in space, but we later learn about some

> survivors who emerge after 5,000 years underground.